# Adding Multipoint layer OpenLayers for snap interaction

Tags: openlayers, well-known-text, multipoint

I am trying to implement snap on my map, getting snap nodes as a multipoint wkt as snap_nodes and creating and adding a layer, but the layer doesn't show

snap_nodes = MULTIPOINT((350095.29 650021.37),(350097.44 650021.59),(350098.11 650025.77),(350098.72 650028.78),(350099.32 650030.98),(350099.52 650031.48),(350100.03 650032.29),(350100.63 650033.19),(350101.64 650034.2),(350102.35 650034.7),(350103.05 650035),(350103.25 650035.1),(350104.16 650035.21))

```
const geometry = wkt.readGeometry(snap_nodes, {      
      dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
      featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
    });
      let feature = new Feature(geometry);
      style: new Style({
        stroke : new Stroke({
          color: 'blue',
          width: 2
        }),
        fill : new Fill({color:'red'})
      })
      const snapVectorSource = new VectorSource({
        features: [feature]
      });
     const snapLayer = new VectorLayer({
        source: snapVectorSource
      });     
     this._map.addLayer(snapLayer);
```

Comment: Where (approximately) should be these points located?

Comment: @TomazicM somewhere in Scotland

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you specify `dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326'` for reading WKT geometry. Your WKT coordinates are definitely not `EPSG:4326`, they are way to high. They are also not `EPSG:3857`, they are way to low for that to be in Scotland.

Since coordinates are in Scotland, UK, primary suspect for correct CRS is British National Grid, which is `EPSG:27700`.

So the following code:

```
proj4.defs('EPSG:27700', '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 ' +
    '+x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy ' +
    '+towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 ' +
    '+units=m +no_defs');
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

var snap_nodes = 'MULTIPOINT((350095.29 650021.37),(350097.44 650021.59),(350098.11 650025.77),(350098.72 650028.78),(350099.32 650030.98),(350099.52 650031.48),(350100.03 650032.29),(350100.63 650033.19),(350101.64 650034.2),(350102.35 650034.7),(350103.05 650035),(350103.25 650035.1),(350104.16 650035.21))';

var geometry = new ol.format.WKT().readGeometry(snap_nodes, {      
  dataProjection: 'EPSG:27700',
  featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
});
```

places points somewhere in Scotland:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I am using snap with draw interaction, but still it does not snap to the points displayed on the same layer. I checked with setting the projections same for data and features. What can I try more?

Comment: There is no snap interaction code in your question. This answer correctly answers your question as it is. If answer helped you solve you problem, it's customary on GIS SE site to mark it as accepted, to let others with similar problems know that problem was resolved. If you have a new question, post it as a separate question.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question to include code for draw as well which I'm trying in dev.

Comment: GIS SE site has policy of focused questions which among other things means one question per question. If you have new/additional question, please post it as a separate question.

Comment: great thanks! will do